# I can't compare chunks to strings (nodejs)

Tags: string, node.js, stdin, chunks

This function won't throw the error when I type "end" to the console, but will write the chunk (whatever I type in) to the console as a string with no problems:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
    var chunk = process.stdin.read();
    if (chunk == "end") {
        throw new Error("user has ended script");
    }
    if (chunk !== null) {
        process.stdout.write(chunk);
    }
});
```

I'm sure there's something totally obvious that I must be missing.  I tried calling `.toString()` on the chunk before comparing but it made no difference.

Comment: not sure but guessing there might be a trailing newline or something like that

Comment: what error are you expecting.. its a readable stream.. type in end and see if it throws err

Comment: Naeem, sorry my question was unclear.  I want the error to get thrown when I type "end" but it doesn't.

Comment: MightyPork, I added this line to the script `chunk.replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/g,"");` to try to rule that out, but I get the same result.  Is there a way to print a string along with its hidden symbols? (that would probably be a better way to check)

Comment: When in doubt, `chunk.split("").length`.

Comment: Okay, I got it.  MightyPork was right.  There is a "\r\n" at the end of each chunk, which I'm not sure why my regex didn't find that, but it's working now.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Actually, I AM sure why my regex didnt work... I forgot to assign the result to chunk.. oops :O